# Please help me solve this radical.

Tags: contest-math, radicals

Please show me how does $\sqrt{12\sqrt[3]{2} - 15}$ + $\sqrt{12\sqrt[3]{4} - 12}$ = 3. I can't find the answer anywhere else.

The answer in the book also says
$$\left(\sqrt{12\sqrt[3]{2} - 15} + \sqrt{12\sqrt[3]{4} - 12}\right)^2 = 12\sqrt[3]{2} + 12\sqrt[3]{4} - 27 + 2 = 9$$
which I don't see in my calculation. I can understand the $12\sqrt[3]{2} + 12\sqrt[3]{4} - 27$ but where does the $+ 2$ come from? Cuz instead of $+ 2$, I've got $+ 2\sqrt{204-144\sqrt[3]{2}+180\sqrt[3]{4}}$. I don't see how it's the same number.

Comment: Why don't you try solving the problem istead of just looking for the answer somewhere else?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen are you sure that it is the exact problem because even calculator is showing that left side is equal to 2.111123969 i hope some thing is wrong in the question

Comment: @MdjavedAkhtar If you look at the edit history, you can see the original formatting, which seems clear enough that this is the question that was asked (though transcription errors are possible). You can also see that it was Gary, not Jyrki who formatted the question; Jyrki just got rid of some erroneous tags.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, please solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Gary WTF?! Of course, I've tried to solve it but I couldn't. That's why I've come here. If you don't know the answer, you don't have to say anything at all.

Comment: @MdjavedAkhtar No, the Google's calculator says the combination of both is exactly 3.

Comment: Square it and it will look like $A+2\sqrt{B}$. Now just check if $(9-A)^2/4=B$.

Comment: Mathjax tip: You should try learning some [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question, as it is difficult to read. You can put mathematics between `$` signs, e.g. `$x+1$` produces $x+1$. To produce $\sqrt{a + b}$, you write `$\sqrt{a + b}$` (the curly braces collect everything under the square root). If you want a cube root, try `$\sqrt[3]{a + b}$` instead. Press edit, and see how Gary formatted your original equation. See if you can format your working similarly, and we can then re-open the question.

Comment: +1 and voting to re-open for trying some MathJax. I've fixed it up. Let me know if there's anything wrong, e.g. I've put the square root over too much or too little.

Answer (score 4):

Squaring works of course, though there seems to be an error in the book *and* in your workings as posted above.  For ease let us use $x^3=2$.  Then we need to show

$$\sqrt{12x-15} + \sqrt{12x^2-12} = 3$$
As both sides are positive, equivalently we show the squares on both sides are the same, viz.
$$12x^2+12x-27 + 2\sqrt{(12x-15)(12x^2-12)} = 9$$
$$\iff x^2+x+\sqrt{13-4x-5x^2} = 3$$
We can isolate the radical and once again square to get the equivalent
$$13-4x-5x^2 = (3-x-x^2)^2 \iff (x+2)(x^3-2)= 0$$
which is true obviously.

---

P.S. Another approach would be to denest the outer radical, if possible.

For e.g.
let $\sqrt{12x-15} = a+bx+ cx^2$, then we have
$12x-15 = (a^2+4bc)+2(ab+c^2)x + (2ca+b^2)x^2$.  Hence we need $2ca=-b^2, ab+c^2=6, a^2+4bc=-15 \implies (a, b, c) = (1, 2, -2)$ for a positive solution.  Thus $\sqrt{12\sqrt[3]2-15} = 1 + 2\sqrt[3]2 -2\sqrt[3]4$.

Similarly, $\sqrt{12\sqrt[3]4-12} = 2 - 2\sqrt[3]2+2\sqrt[3]4 $, so the sum is obviously $3$.

Comment: Thank you so much but I still don't know how to solve those equations (2ca = -b^2, ab + c^2 = 6, a^2 + 4bc = 15, et cetera) since none of the variables in each equation is the same and there're 3 variables, not just 2. Can you please explain to me how do you solve them?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make the numbers smaller and the expressions a bit more manageable by dividing through by $\surd12=2\surd3$ and writing $\alpha^3=2$. Then we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{\alpha-\tfrac54}+\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}=\tfrac12\surd3.$$
We can do this by demonstrating the equivalent squared equality, which a little simplification reduces to $$\alpha^2+\alpha-\tfrac94+\sqrt{13-4\alpha-5\alpha^2}=(\tfrac12\surd3)^2,$$ or
$3-\alpha-\alpha^2=\sqrt{13-4\alpha-5\alpha^2}.$
This identity is easily verified, again, by squaring and simplifying.